# Restore a disk from a snapshot in XEN 4.6

Tags: dd, xen, snapshot

I created a snapshot with

```
lvcreate -n snap01.vm01 -L 5G -s vg0/vm01.eclabs.de
```

now I did some stuff on my disk i don't want to keep and want to revert it to the snapshot point.

How do I restore the snapshot?

I tried to copy the snapshot with `dd` like:

```
dd if=/dev/vg0/snap01.vm01 | pv | dd of=/dev/vg0/vm01.eclabs.de-restore
```

but although the file is only 5GB the dd process continues to copy things for hours. Is this sthe correct way?

Answer (score 0):

You can restore an LVM snapshot with

```
lvconvert --merge <snapshot path>
```

In the example above: To revert back to `snap0.vm01` snapshot, which was taken for `vg0/vm01.eclabs.de` :

```
umount  /dev/vg0/vm01.eclabs.de
lvconvert --merge /dev/vg0/snap01.vm01
```

see http://www.switchroot.com/how-to-rollback-a-lvm-volume-to-its-snapshot